# how to clear the condition filter when main filter is empty in aggrid

Tags: angular8, ag-grid

I am using an ag-grid and i have enabled filtering, now i when type something in the filter textbox then the conditional filter is automatically shown.

My requirement is to clear the conditional filter text box when main filter textbox is cleared.

Below is the code i tried but i dont know how to check if the textbox is empty or not and how to clear the conditional textbox when the main textbox is cleared.

```
onFilterChanged: function(filterParams) {console.info('alert');},
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen to events on your textbox and as soon as it is cleared, you call the grid api

```
gridOptions.api.setFilterModel(null);
```

Comment: Yes i know that but how to listen. It is not the textbox that i created it is ag-grid filter textbox so how to do that?